# Filtering on an calendar event's location properties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I would like to filter on the `location` property of an `event`, more specifically the `displayName`:

```
"location": { 
  "displayName": "Conference Room - Baker", 
  "locationType": "default", 
  "uniqueId": "Conference Room - Baker", 
  "uniqueIdType": "private" 
}
```

I can filter based on the `subject` using:

```
/me/calendarview?startdatetime=01-01-2019&enddatetime=12-31-2019&$filter=(isorganizer eq true) and startsWith(subject,'Project')&$top=100&$select=subject,organizer,attendees,start,end,location&$orderby=start/dateTime
```

The above query seems to work to filter on the subject but when I try to filter on `location/displayName`:

```
/me/calendarview?startdatetime=01-01-2019&enddatetime=12-31-2019&$filter=(isorganizer eq true) and startsWith(location/displayname,'Conference')&$top=100&$select=subject,organizer,attendees,start,end,location&$orderby=start/dateTime
```

I get the below error:

[image]

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#event), `location` should be filterable:

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to work this out?  Seems like the problem is with "startsWith" since if I just filter with a `location/displayName eq 'wherever'` it seems to work.